# Haskell Error - No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to create a function which adds a 1 before each of the entries in a given list. I haven't quite grasped the syntax for Haskell and am wondering what is wrong with this code. For example, I would like this to return the list [1,1,1,2,1,3]

```
ins1 :: [a] -> [a]
ins1 [x] = [x]
ins1 (x:xs) = [1] ++ [x] ++ ins1(xs)

main = print(ins1 [1,2,3])
```

I get the error:

```
• No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’
  Possible fix:
    add (Num a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        ins1 :: [a] -> [a]
• In the expression: 1
  In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘[1]’
  In the expression: [1] ++ [x] ++ ins1 (xs)
<interactive>:3:1: error:
• Variable not in scope: main
• Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: You should add the `Num a` typeconstraint in the signature, like the error says.

Comment: Furthermore I have the idea that there is a semantical error in your code.

Answer (score 7):

Well like the error says, you use `ins1`, and you write `[1] ++ [x] ++ ...`.

Now `1` is a numerical literal, so it can take all *numerical types*. Hence `1` has type `Num b => b`, as a result `[1]` has type `Num b => [b]`.

Later you append the list with `x` and recursion, hence we now know that `a ~ b` (`a` and `b` are the same type). So we have to add a type constraint to the signature for `a`:

```
ins1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
ins1 [x] = [x]
ins1 (x:xs) = [1] ++ [x] ++ ins1(xs)
```

This solves the compile error, but probably will *not* generate what you want. Since now there is *no* case for the empty list. Indeed, both the `[x]` pattern and the `(x:xs)` pattern work with lists that respectively match with lists with *exactly one* element, and *at least* one element.

Therefore I think that your first clause should actually match the empty list:

```
ins1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
ins1 [] = []
ins1 (x:xs) = [1] ++ [x] ++ ins1(xs)
```

There is also an inefficiency in the second clause: you append to a list of one element, so we can use the "*cons*" data cosntructor `(:)` here:

```
ins1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
ins1 [] = []
ins1 (x:xs) = 1 : x : ins1 xs
```

This will insert a `1` for *every* element in the original list, so:

```
Prelude> ins1 [1, 4, 2, 5]
[1,1,1,4,1,2,1,5]
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a quick response! Just to clarify, why would the use of append be more inefficient than the cons constructor.

Comment: @SamuelBarkes: because `(:)` is a data constructor, so you use the constructor immediately, and then it is done. Using `(++)` is a function that uses recursion, it will require two recursive steps, and furthermore thus apply the cons `(:)` internally. You can here see its function definition: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%2B%2B

Answer (score 1):

If you give me a function of type `[a] -> [a]`, you’re saying that, *for all* types `a` that *I* choose, if I give you a list of values of type `a`, then you can give me back a list of elements of that type.

So if I choose `a` to be `Int` by giving you `[2, 3, 4] :: [Int]`, then all is well: the literal `1` in the implementation of `ins1` is constrained from `Num t => t` by `t` = `Int` to `Num Int => Int`. That works because there is an `instance Num Int`.

However, if I choose `a` to be `Char`, by giving you `['a', 'b', 'c']` (= `"abc"`), then `t` = `Char`, giving `Num Char => Char`, which is an error because there’s no `instance Num Char`. Therefore, this is a *counterexample* for the type: your function doesn’t work *for all* `a`, only those `a` that have an instance of `Num`. So you need to express this constraint in the type signature:

```
ins1 :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
```

The compiler can infer this for you, and will display a warning about a missing type signature if `-Wall` is enabled (or `-Wmissing-signatures` specifically). This will also warn about the fact that `ins1` is *non-exhaustive*: you don’t handle the case of an empty input list. Alternatively, you can enter the definition into GHCi and ask for its type with `:type ins1` or `:t ins1`.

Generic functions in Haskell are *parametrically polymorphic*, which means that if you have an unconstrained type variable like `a`, you know *nothing* about it, not even that it can be constructed from a number literal. So the *only* things a function of type `[a] -> [a]` can do are copy, rearrange, or drop elements from the input, or fail to terminate (loop infinitely or raise an error)—it can’t construct new elements or perform any class-specific operations on those elements, such as `+` from `Num` or `<` from `Ord`.

This may sound limiting, but in fact it’s incredibly useful: the less you know about a type, the fewer options you have for *misusing* it. And by a neat trick called the Curry–Howard correspondence, you can examine a polymorphic function type like `head :: [a] -> a` and think of it as a logical formula: does having a list of `a` imply you can get an `a`? No, because the list may be empty. So you know that a `head` function with this type *must* raise an error if the input is empty, because it has no generic way to construct an `a`.